# I need to choose random function in C++ project

Tags: c++, random

I am making a C++ game-project and in the game I need to choose random bonuses (functions).

(below is the example of the code)

```
void triple_balls(){
    /* CODE */
}

void longer_paddle(){
    /* CODE */
}

void shorter_paddle(){
    /* CODE */
}

void bonus_activator(){
    //Here I must choose one of the 3 functions above
    //FIXME
}
```

Comment: What's the question?  Write some code instead of asking us to do your work.

Comment: This smells suspiciously like homework to me

Comment: Generate a random number and then use `if` or `switch` to choose a function to call.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`std::function`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function), to store you functions in a container.
Then create an array of `std::function` of size `3`.

```cpp
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>

void triple_balls() { /* YOUR CODE */ }

void longer_paddle() { /* YOUR CODE */ }

void shorter_paddle() { /* YOUR CODE */ }

void bonus_activator(){
    std::function<void(void)> farr[3] = 
    {
        triple_balls,
        longer_paddle,
        shorter_paddle
    };
    farr[rand() % 3]();
}
```

Comment: The downside of `std::function` is that it may use dynamic allocation. A simple function pointer might be more efficient.

Comment: and the size of `std::function` is large so it may not be efficient in many cases

Comment: @phuclv It's just an another method

Answer (score 3):

Use a function pointer array instead

```
using BonusFunc = void (*)();
BonusFunc[3] = { triple_balls, longer_paddle, shorter_paddle };

void bonus_activator(){
    BonusFunc[rand() % 3](); // just an example, don't use rand() in real code
}
```

Comment: Of course you can use rand on real code. It's not always recruited to have a "perfectly " equally distributed distribution. Rand is accurate enough for many applications.

Answer (score 0):

```
std::array{
  &triple_balls,
  &longer_paddle,
  &shorter_paddle,
}
.at(rand() % 3)();
```

fits in only one-line and no variables needed and the optimizer will likely reduce this into a switch-statement-like operation:

```
std::array{ &triple_balls, &longer_paddle, &shorter_paddle }.at(rand() % 3)();
```

Comment: Note that rand() is a c-function consider using std::uniform_int_distribution for all random-ness in your game. It generates higher quality random numbers and can generate for any numeric type.